# jquery autocomplete data format

Tags: format, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to display jSON data in jQuery autocomplete, and everything works fine except the dropdown doesnt show up.
I could use `parse:` (for which there is a ton of examples) but i think i need the data to be displayed through `source:`.

**is it possible to display data the way i am doing or do we need parse?

if yes, how?**

Im not very good with jquery UI

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div/>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).attr( "scrollTop", 0 );
    }

    $( "#aut_teachers" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url+"controller/model",
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data.value);// here is where the problem is
                }

            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In jQuery, data is already your JSON object.
I think you don't need to use data.value.
Can you present a example of your JSON data?

Comment: yes, here:
{"response":"true","message":[{"value":"Wren  J  Thomas","label":"1262"},{"value":"Wiseman  Kim","label":"1257"},{"value":"Whitman","label":"1249"},{"value":"Whitehead  Marcia","label":"1248"},{"value":"White  Maja","label":"1247"}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `data.message` as a parameter do `response` instead of `data.value`.

Since, `data.message` is a array of objects, and the objects are label/value, you can use it.

Check [Autocomplete Docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) for more information.